# how to get current layout direction in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, layout, flutter-layout, direction

I'm working on an application that should also work with RTL layout direction (Arabic and Hebrew languages).

I also need to perform some changes in the layout in case the layout direction is
RTL.

How can I determine what is the current layout direction of the app?

Comment: @xxx what is the connection to the question you posted? the question you posted talks about screen orientation (meaning portrait or landscape). My question is regarding layout direction (meaning left-to-right or right-to-left). Please validate that the question is indeed duplicate before you flag it as one!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can get the current direction using `Directionality.of`.

```dart
final TextDirection currentDirection = Directionality.of(context);
final bool isRTL = currentDirection == TextDirection.rtl;
```

which determines `the direction of the selctedlanguage but if need you to set it manually, probably this can work for you.

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    theme: ThemeData(),
    home: Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
      child: Home(),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. **Add this method to your class :**

```dart
bool isRTL() => Directionality.of(context).toString().contains(TextDirection.RTL.value.toLowerCase());
```

2. **Usage in the build() method :**

```dart
RichText(
   textAlign: isRTL() ? TextAlign.right : TextAlign.left,
   .....
),
```

Comment: i have simplified it to  bool isRtl = Directionality.of(context).index == 0;